# Does XmlSerializer.Deserialize load the entire document in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

Does `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` load the entire document in memory before constructing the target object?

The content of the XML is coming from client side which I don't fully trust. Therefore I'm using XmlReader to parse it in a forward-only, non-looking-back fashion. Although `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` can deserialize from XmlReader, what I'm not sure is that whether it caches the entire document it reads from XmlReader into memory and therefore poses memory pressure to the system. which will be undesirable.

I looked at the MSDN, but it doesn't seem to mention it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think that is the work of OS. It manages this issue with paging mechanism.

Comment: @MuctadirDinar: **no**, the OS has nothing to do with it, and he's not asking about when the bits are in memory; he's asking when the bits get parsed into a document or set of nodes which are in memory.

Comment: You should consider creating your own class derived from `XmlReader`. Your class could simply ignore anything it doesn't trust, becoming a source of a trusted sequence of nodes for the XML Serializer (or LINQ to XML) to consume.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Implementing my own XmlReader doesn't help here. .Net XmlReader is already serial. However my question is whether the XmlSerializer, which uses XmlReader underlying, will load the whole document into memory, and *then* does deserialization. I personally don't think that's the case, but by looking at MSDN, I can't confirm that, and I don't either have a way to verify through testing.

Comment: I'm saying that you can implement your own XmlReader and pass your new reader to XmlSerializer. Even if it wants to load the whole thing, it would only be loading those nodes you permitted to pass. Or is your question about the _size_ of the document and not about the contents?

Comment: No, because XmlSerialize can still potentially cache all the contents that the reader passes to it. If there're a large amount of such data, the XmlSerializer is essentially holding a large amount of data in the memory, and therefore poses memory pressure to the server. This boils down to how Xmlserializer gets implemented by .NET, which is why I was looking into MSDN for answer. But there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Test it by making a massive Xml document and passing it in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, it doesn't.

I came here with exactly the same question and was surprised that there were no answer.
Firstly, I had thought about test, but then I decided to go deeper and see it myself.
So I've spent quite some time to study how does serialization/deserialization work, explored .NET Framework source code and dynamically generated assembly.
Here are the key code parts with my comments from my little investigation (insignificant parts omitted).

Suppose we given:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    var foobars = (List<Foobar>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

After that we would get to this `XmlSerializer` class method:

```
public object Deserialize(TextReader textReader) 
{ 
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
    return Deserialize(xmlReader, null); 
}
```

Which leads us to:

```
public object Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
{
    // instantiate specific for our class Reader 
    // from dynamically generated assembly
    XmlSerializationReader reader = CreateReader(); 
    reader.Init(xmlReader, events, encodingStyle, tempAssembly); 
    try { 
        //call dynamically generated for out particular type method
        return Deserialize(reader);
    } 
    finally {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Dynamically generated code looks like:

```
public class XmlSerializationReaderList1 : XmlSerializationReader
{
    protected override object Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
    {
        return ((XmlSerializationReaderList1) reader).Read3_ArrayOfFoobar();
    }

    // this is the method which do all work, huge part of it is omitted
    public object Read3_ArrayOfFoobar()
    {
        // this.Reader is XmlSerializationReader field of type XmlReader
        this.Reader.ReadStartElement();
        int num2 = (int) this.Reader.MoveToContent();
        int whileIterations = 0;
        int readerCount = this.ReaderCount;
        while ((this.Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement ? 0 : (this.Reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.None ? 1 : 0)) != 0)
        {
            if (this.Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
            if ((this.Reader.LocalName != this.id3_Foobar ? 0 : (this.Reader.NamespaceURI == this.id2_Item ? 1 : 0)) != 0)
            {
                if (list == null)
                this.Reader.Skip();
                else
                list.Add(this.Read2_Foobar(true, true));
            }
            else
                this.UnknownNode((object) null, ":Foobar");
            }
            else
            this.UnknownNode((object) null, ":Foobar");
            int num3 = (int) this.Reader.MoveToContent();
            this.CheckReaderCount
    }

    private Foobar Read2_Foobar(bool isNullable, bool checkType) { //... }
}
```

`MoveToContent` from `XmlReader` certainly looks like:

```
public virtual XmlNodeType MoveToContent()
{
  do
  {
    switch (this.NodeType)
    {
      case XmlNodeType.Element:
      case XmlNodeType.Text:
      case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
      case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
      case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
      case XmlNodeType.EndEntity:
        return this.NodeType;
      case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
        this.MoveToElement();
        goto case XmlNodeType.Element;
      default:
        continue;
    }
  }
  while (this.Read());
  return this.NodeType;
}
```

Certainly, it was obvious from the beginning that `Deserialize` method implemented in such way, but it was interesting for me to get deeper knowledge of how things work.